# simple javascript convert into function

Tags: javascript

I have a simple javascript that i keep using in every page I have, and I want to make it a function and add some additional feature, if i click that `loading_input(div)` from `display:block` change to `display:none`

I try but I have no luck can someone guide me to make it work..

example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 document.getElementById("instructor").onchange = function() {
    document.getElementById("loading_input").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("instructor").style.color = "#fff";
}
document.getElementById("subject_scheduling").onchange = function() {
    document.getElementById("loading_input").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("subject_scheduling").style.color = "#fff";
}

</script>
```

Comment: thanks for your suggestion but I prepare to use javascript

Comment: What tags are `instructor` and `subject_scheduling` ? You are saying "when i click", so maybe you should use `.onclick` instead of `.onchange`

Comment: @jhunlio Jquery is JavaScript, it's a library.

Comment: @ben `instructor` is an `id` of `input field` where i use to add value before making any event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for all suggestion it help me to come up with this answer.

```
// To haddle my onchange this is what I come up 
function loading(input_id){
  if(input_id){
    document.getElementById("loading_input").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById(input_id).style.color = "#fff";
  }
 }
```

If I need to use it in my page. I just do like this

```
<input id="sample" onchange="loading('sample')" />
```

onclick event

```
 // this is what I come up to haddle my onclick event 
 function close_and_reload(id){
 if(id){
    document.getElementById(id).style.display = "block";
    window.location.reload();
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I made both element Ids parameters to the function, although the code snippet you sent seems like you only change the 2nd one. My version is a bit more flexible but if you know for sure the first one always the same, then you can drop the first parameter.

```
function changeHandler(elem1, elem2){
    document.getElementById(elem1).style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById(elem2).style.color = "#fff";

} 


document.getElementById("instructor").onchange = changeHandler("loading_input", "instructor");

document.getElementById("subject_scheduling").onchange = changeHandler("loading_input", "subject_scheduling");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Select a new car from the list.</p>

<select id="mySelect" onchange="changeStyle('demo');changeColor('demo')">
  <option value="Audi">Audi
  <option value="BMW">BMW
  <option value="Mercedes">Mercedes
  <option value="Volvo">Volvo
</select>


<p id="demo">some content</p>

<script>
function changeStyle(id) {
    document.getElementById(id).style.display = "block";
}

function changeColor(id) {
   document.getElementById(id).style.color = "#fff";
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```